# Overlapping dropdown menu that gets on the way (Selenium/Python)

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu

Dear Stackoverflow members,

I’m very new to Python and Selenium and I’m running into a problem that I can’t find an answer anywhere else.
I’m trying to write a code to get some data from this website: https://www2.bec.sp.gov.br/bec_pregao_UI/OC/pesquisa_publica.aspx (it’s in Portuguese). The first thing I need to do is to perform the following sequence: “Todas as situações – Consultar Situações -> Encerrado -> Encerrado com Vencedor”.
I’m stuck in the very first step, which is to click on the dropdown menu where it is written “Todas as situações – Consultar Situações”. The code I’m running is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get( "https://www2.bec.sp.gov.br/bec_pregao_UI/OC/pesquisa_publica.aspx")
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='fake_grupo_status']/div[1]").click()
```

What I think is happening is that when the site opens, somehow the mouse goes over where it is written “Mural” and then another dropdown menu opens and then when it clicks, it clicks on the wrong link. I’ve tried to first move the mouse to the footer of the page and then wait for 10 seconds and just after that perform the action I want… but it is still not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried manually recording the test in the Selenium IDE plugin for Firefox then looking at the source?

Comment: I've tried recording using the Selenium IDE plugin. It works fine when I test it on the IDE itself but when I try to export the code to python, I run on the same issue...

Comment: Update: I used Chrome WebDrive and it worked! So it seems to be something with Firefox/Selenium Python implementation. Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Helium](http://heliumhq.com/) instead of Selenium? I have just managed to achieve what you needed in a short Helium script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from helium.api import *
start_firefox("https://www2.bec.sp.gov.br/bec_pregao_UI/OC/pesquisa_publica.aspx")
click(u'Todas Situações - Consultar Situações')
click(u'Encerrado')
click(u'Encerrado com Vencedor')
```

After installing Helium library just save the above lines into a .py file (for example, script.py) and run

```
> python script.py
```

from the command line. It seems to work without any problems.

*Disclaimer: I'm one of Helium's developers.*

Comment: Thank you very much @Tytus! I've never used Helium but it is certainly worth a try.